# Riley likes to make a barbecued favorite that comes from swine

Tags: riddle, wordplay, word-property

Since my last riddle was solved so fast, I decided to do a two-part riddle that is a bit trickier. I hope you enjoy! :D

> Lacey loves to do thigh-strengthening exercises and always put her best foot forward.
>
> Riley likes to make a barbecued favorite that usually comes from swine.
>
> Heather thinks she's good at causing lighthearted laughter and amusement (but she isn't).
>
> Fabian is always telling "little" lies.
>
> Stephanie tries to keep a serious and unrelenting voice of authority in the presence of her misbehaving Chihuahua.
>
> Raquan enjoys finding lines in circles.

Do you know what these friends have in common?

For your question to be accepted, you must explain all of the hints! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think

> They all like to do things with the first letters of their names in them, and these are all bones in the body!! @Crozier tells me it could also be parts of the body.

So:
Lacey loves to do thigh-strengthening exercises and always put her best foot forward.

> Lacey loves lunges. (PHALANGES) or LUNGS, per @Crozier.

Riley likes to make a barbecued favorite that usually comes from swine.

> Riley loves ribs. (RIBS)

Heather thinks she's good at causing lighthearted laughter and amusement (but she isn't).

> Heather thinks she’s humorous. (HUMERUS)

Fabian is always telling "little" lies.

> Fabian loves fibbing. (FIBULA)

Stephanie tries to keep a serious and unrelenting voice of authority in the presence of her misbehaving Chihuahua.

> Stephanie is stern. (STERNUM)

Raquan enjoys finding lines in circles.

> Raquan loves radius. (RADIUS)

Comment: You are on the right track, but you still must guess the overall theme as well! :D @El-Guest

Comment: @Crozier isn’t the first line the common theme? Are all of my individual answers right?

Comment: That is not the common theme and all of your individual answers are correct, except, it would be easier to guess if Raquan's clue was in singular form! You are very close! :D

Comment: How does this look now, @Crozier? This was a clever one!!

Comment: Very good, I was aiming for the theme to be just parts of the body and the first clue to be "lungs", but I will accept your answer as well! and thanks! :)

Comment: I thought it could’ve and should’ve been lungs, but all the rest were bones and I didn’t want to break the streak! This was a really fun one @Crozier, I enjoyed it!